# How to make a list item (li) clicked by default on page load in Vue JS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

In Vue JS, how to make a list item(li) clicked by default on page load. I am iterating the numbers list using the li element. Clicking on '#" will return all records, Clicking on number 1 will return records that starts with 1 like 100, 101, etc. On page load, I have to make '#' selected by default. How to do this in Vue JS?

Vue JS Version: 2.6.12

Code:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <ul class="numbersInput">
            <li v-for="number in numbers" :key="number"><a
                href="javascript:;" @click="numberStartsWith(number)">{{ number }}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="results">
            <!-- iterating logic for # to return all records-->
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'SearchByNumber',
  data() {
    return {
      numbersList: ['100','101','102','103','104',
                    '200','201','202','203','204',
                    '300','301','302','303','304',],
        };    
   },
  computed: {
    numbers() {
      const nums = ['#', '1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10',];
      return nums;
    },
  },
  methods: {
      numberStartsWith(input) {
      if(input==='#'){
       // return numbersList
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
<style>
.numbersInput {
    display:flex;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this will be to add a line in the component's `mounted` method:

```js
export default {
  name: 'SearchByNumber',
  data () {
    ...  
  },
  computed: {
    ...
  },
  methods: {
    numberStartsWith(input) {
      ...
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.numberStartsWith('#')
  }
};
```

Any code written in a `mounted` method is called after the DOM has loaded and the template has been rendered, which means it's the right time for you to "simulate" a click by calling the required piece of code.

To learn more, you can check out this link: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html

Comment: I want to set the class active for '#' list item in mounted hook

Comment: You can just do that in the template itself, and it'll be set on render